# T-sql Subquery within Subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I'm fairly new to SQL server and am learning as I go so sorry if the answer is obvious or I'm just approaching this in the complete wrong way.

I'm moving a query from access to SQL server, the query in question has sub-queries within sub-queries.

```
WITH CalculateSPBalance AS
( SELECT [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number], ([Promoter Codes].[Promoter's Price] + [Promoter Codes].[Resform Deposit] * [Promoter Codes].[Resform Deposit deducted from sp] -
        [Venue Codes].[Event Price]) - [Venue Codes].[Event Deposit] * [BOOKINGS FILE].[Charity paid event deposit] AS [SP Balance]
   FROM [BOOKINGS FILE]
   INNER JOIN [Promoter Codes] ON [BOOKINGS FILE].[Promoter Code] = [Promoter Codes].[Promoter Code]
   INNER JOIN [Venue Codes]    ON [BOOKINGS FILE].[Venue Code] = [Venue Codes].[Venue Code]

)
, CalculateSPBeingHeld AS
( SELECT [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number], SUM([Sponsorship Collected].Amount) AS [SP held]
   FROM [BOOKINGS FILE]
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [Sponsorship Collected] ON [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] = [Sponsorship Collected].[Booking Number]
   WHERE ([Sponsorship Collected].[Received by] = N'holding')
   GROUP BY [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number]
)
SELECT [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number],
CASE
    WHEN CalculateSPBeingHeld.[SP held] IS NULL
    THEN 0
    ELSE CalculateSPBeingHeld.[sp held] - CalculateSPBalance.[SP Balance]
END AS test
FROM [Bookings file]

INNER JOIN CalculateSPBalance   ON[BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] = CalculateSPBalance.[Booking Number]
INNER JOIN CalculateSPBeingHeld ON[BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] = CalculateSPBeingHeld.[Booking Number]

ORDER BY [booking number]
```

as I understand it the two subs are defined and used within the overall query.

This works fine.

How would I then use these results as part of a larger query

ie

```
WITH test2 AS
    (
        CalculateSPBalance AS
        ( SELECT [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number], ([Promoter Codes].[Promoter's Price] + [Promoter Codes].[Resform Deposit] * [Promoter Codes].[Resform Deposit deducted from sp] -
                [Venue Codes].[Event Price]) - [Venue Codes].[Event Deposit] * [BOOKINGS FILE].[Charity paid event deposit] AS [SP Balance]
           FROM [BOOKINGS FILE]
           INNER JOIN [Promoter Codes] ON [BOOKINGS FILE].[Promoter Code] = [Promoter Codes].[Promoter Code]
           INNER JOIN [Venue Codes]    ON [BOOKINGS FILE].[Venue Code] = [Venue Codes].[Venue Code] )
        , CalculateSPBeingHeld AS
        ( SELECT [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number]                                              , SUM([Sponsorship Collected].Amount) AS [SP held]
           FROM [BOOKINGS FILE]
           LEFT OUTER JOIN [Sponsorship Collected] ON [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] = [Sponsorship Collected].[Booking Number]
           WHERE ([Sponsorship Collected].[Received by] = N'holding')
           GROUP BY [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] 
        )


        SELECT [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number],
                CASE
                    WHEN CalculateSPBeingHeld.[SP held] IS NULL
                    THEN 0
                    ELSE CalculateSPBeingHeld.[sp held] - CalculateSPBalance.[SP Balance]
                END AS test
        FROM [Bookings file]

        INNER JOIN CalculateSPBalance   ON[BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] = CalculateSPBalance.[Booking Number]
        INNER JOIN CalculateSPBeingHeld ON[BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] = CalculateSPBeingHeld.[Booking Number]

        ORDER BY [booking number]
    )

SELECT *
FROM test2
```

So I want to use this dataset made up of sub queries as a subquery within a larger query

thanks in advanced

Comment: What is the question?  And work on the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `test2` another [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175972%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

```
WITH  CalculateSPBalance AS
        ( 
                SELECT [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number], ([Promoter Codes].[Promoter's Price] + [Promoter Codes].[Resform Deposit] * [Promoter Codes].[Resform Deposit deducted from sp] -
                [Venue Codes].[Event Price]) - [Venue Codes].[Event Deposit] * [BOOKINGS FILE].[Charity paid event deposit] AS [SP Balance]
                FROM [BOOKINGS FILE]
                INNER JOIN [Promoter Codes] ON [BOOKINGS FILE].[Promoter Code] = [Promoter Codes].[Promoter Code]
                INNER JOIN [Venue Codes]    ON [BOOKINGS FILE].[Venue Code] = [Venue Codes].[Venue Code] )
        , CalculateSPBeingHeld AS
        ( 
                SELECT [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number]                                              , SUM([Sponsorship Collected].Amount) AS [SP held]
                FROM [BOOKINGS FILE]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [Sponsorship Collected] ON [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] = [Sponsorship Collected].[Booking Number]
                WHERE ([Sponsorship Collected].[Received by] = N'holding')
                GROUP BY [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] 
        )
        , test2 as (


                SELECT [BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number],
                        CASE
                            WHEN CalculateSPBeingHeld.[SP held] IS NULL
                            THEN 0
                            ELSE CalculateSPBeingHeld.[sp held] - CalculateSPBalance.[SP Balance]
                        END AS test
                FROM [Bookings file]

                INNER JOIN CalculateSPBalance   ON[BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] = CalculateSPBalance.[Booking Number]
                INNER JOIN CalculateSPBeingHeld ON[BOOKINGS FILE].[Booking Number] = CalculateSPBeingHeld.[Booking Number]

    )

SELECT *
FROM test2                 
ORDER BY [booking number]
```

Note that ordering within CTEs is not supported (with few exceptions) and therefore the ordering is done outside of the CTE definitions.